# Apache webserver crashing!

Tags: php, mysql, apache2, wampserver

I am using a Wampserver 2.0 for database-web development.
When i ran the following the php code which is embbeded in my html form, the server crashes meanwhile other php processes on different pages are responding effectively.
I have checked my apache error log and saw the following message: 
[Fri Oct 22 11:37:04 2010] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] File does not exist: C:/wamp/www/setapro/setapro, referer: 
This is php code i executed:

```
<?php 
include 'db_inc.php';
$sql    = "select AVG(no_of_satelites) as 'Mean Number of Satelites', AVG(         height_of_geoid ) as'Mean of HDOP', AVG(rmc_gga_longitude) as 'Mean of Longitude', AVG(rmc_gga_latitude) as 'Mean of latitude'  FROM total_rmcs_ggas ";
$result = mysql_query($sql, $link);
if (!$result) {
die("Query to show averages from table failed");
}
echo 'Number of rows returned from query = '.mysql_num_rows($result) or die();
echo "<h2>Table:Averages for the GPS Receiver</h2>";
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
echo $row['Mean Number of Satelites'].' '.$row['Mean of HDOP'].' '.$row['Mean of  Longitude'].' '.$row['Mean of latitude'].'<br />';
}
mysql_free_result($result);
mysql_close();
?>
```

I do not know which file it is talking about as i have all the files in my document root. I need some assistance here. thank you. the "setapro" is the project folder name and not the file.

Comment: Define "Server crashes". What happens exactly?

Comment: What IDE are you using? Try commentign the code to the point where the apache stops crashing to locate the problem, if the problem is in the code at all. I have some doubts about that.

Comment: I am using eclipse. I suppose to have used mysql_close($link) instead of mysql_close(). It was my mistake. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I just figured out that the mysql_close() was empty and I had to include the resource there in like this:mysql_close($link). Without this, the server crashes.